# How to differentiate $y=|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

For $x \in \mathbb R /\{0\}$

How can I derive that $y'=\frac{x}{|x|}$ ?

I did it by using product rule a chain rule.

But how to prove this only using the definition?

Comment: Write out the definition of |x|

Comment: I don't think this is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution: use piecewise definition.

$$y=|x|=\begin{cases}
x,&\text{for }x\geqslant0\\
-x,&\text{for }x<0
\end{cases}$$

Then you have

$$y'=\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{for }x>0\\
-1,&\text{for }x<0
\end{cases}$$

The derivative $y'$ doesn't exist for $x=0$ because the limit $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$$ doesn't exist. Then just notice that $y'=\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$ for $x\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$$
Applying chain rule after differentiating, we get $$f'(x)=\frac12(x^2)^{-\frac12}.2x=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2}}$$
But what is $\sqrt{x^2}$? It is $f(x)=|x|$. And hence $$f'(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$$
But this derivative is non-defined at $x=0$, so we get that this function is non differentiable at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rewrite $|x|$ as $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: The $ \sqrt{} $ is associated with $ \pm $, positive by convention only when magnitude is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is not defined at point of slope discontinuity $(x=0)$ the derivative follows the rule

$ x<0$ , $y^{'}(x) = -1 $ , $ x>0 , y^{'} (x) = +1 $

Comment: Actually, the derivative *can be* defined at a point of slope discontinuity. The function $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$ has a slope discontinuity at $x=0,$ but $f'(0)$ exists (it's equal to $0).$ In general, a discontinuity at a point does not imply non-existence at that point.